# External links using markdown not working on jekyll "posts"

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I have a jekyll site that I am trying to create some external links in the posts and both markdown and html is getting stripped when building. When I look at the source of the built site its just the text. This is only happening in the posts...when I add a markdown link within a page it works fine. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks. Below is an example:

in my post.md file
    `This is a link to [Google](https://google.com)`

when viewing the source from the index.html for home page out of _site directory the post shows up correctly but 'Google' is not a link, just text.

index.html source:

`<p>This is a link to Google</p>`

I have tried to add just an html  tag as well in the post.md file but that provides the same results.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please include your code in the question. Please show us the original content of the post and the rendered output from the `_site` directory. I couldn't understand what you mean with "html is getting stripped".

Comment: Hi Keith...thanks, I totally for got to post the code, editing original post.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick, Unfortunately, this is still not enough info. The code you included should work. I think you have some issues with Liquid. Can you try using Liquid for something else, such as `_include` file and see if it renders? Have you checked the build output? Are there any errors shown? Is there anything in your `_config` file that may interfere?

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for bearing with me on this stuff...this is my first Jekyll deploy and still getting familiar with things. As far as Liquid, everything seems to be working everywhere else. The site is rendering and links using markdown syntax work in pages, just not posts. I am not getting any errors on the build output, it completes and renders everything else. I have checked the _config and cannot find anything in there that should block it, however I am using a theme...I will reach out to the author of the theme as well and see if I can get anywhere.  Thanks again!

Comment: I got it tracked down...its not that it is working improperly, it does not have the function built in. On the post page (where multiple posts are shown) the links do not work by design. Upon clicking on the post to read that one specifically the links are there and working.

Comment: Most definitely part of the theme design it turns out. In the layout of the home page it is using strip_html. I need to play around some more to get it working the way I want but at least got that part tracked down. Thanks for the guidance Keith.

Comment: You're welcome. Any time :) I added an answer so you can close this question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As stated by the OP. This is a theme issue and not a bug.